# Using JavaScript to get the previous value of a form in order to create the next

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel-5

Probably best if I show you what I have first.  I am using PHP/MySQL and Laravel 5.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p><b>Assign a category:</b></p>
    @foreach (App\Http\Models\GalleryCategories::all() as $category)            
        {!! Form::label('category_id', $category->name) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('category_id', $category->id, null, ['class' => 'field']) !!}                
    @endforeach
</div>
```

That part gets some categories from the database, loops through and creates a series of radio boxes so that the uploader can select one.  Only one.

However what I need is some code, I am told JavaScript is best to get the ID of the category the uploader has selected in order to then do another loop for sub category list connected to the category.

Of course the issue is that I need to pass the category ID the user has chosen before the form is submitted.  In effect I need to have the $category_id available as soon as the person selects one in order to then generate the next set of radio boxes.

Anyone ideas how to do that?

Comment: On a Laravel forum, perhaps best in their view rather than best overall, however not really sure that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to show/disable a set of sub categories based on the selected value of the category? Please reword your question if you can. You may also want to consider sorting out your data in the controller then your view will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yes, I want to show a set of sub categories based on the selected value of the category.  Not sure what you mean by sorting the the data in the controller.  The data has been passed to the view correctly, this is about displaying it, I would not do what I am doing in the form from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, used some javascript to setup an onclick event that passed the Id to the next part of the form.